# Drupal 7 and Image Style problems

Tags: 7, media

I have created several image styles in Drupal 7 (thumbnail, medium, large and xlarge). I also have created a script that imports data from a CSV-file, and copy images to the system.

The script seems to work fine and all images are attached to nodes correctly. Using Views I have created a block that shows nodes of a certain node type, and thumbnails attached to said node. Links to the images is OK in HTML.

Now the problem starts. Some images (thumbnails and large) get created, but some doesn't.

I can not find a reason why the images that doesn't get created should not be created. At first I thought maybe the image size was to big, but this isn't the case. Some images that gets created are bigger than ones that doesn't, and all images are bellow the systems 32 MB limit (from 3 to about 15 MB).

I have no idea where to start looking. All images copied during the import seems fine when opening on my system (OS X).

Can anyone point me to where I can get started at finding what the problem might be?

Thanks!

Comment: Oh, and one more thing. Some thumbnails that get created does not have a large style image created.

Comment: Jeez how embarrassing! This was a file permission problem :O

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I commented on the question, this was a file permission problem..